# java.lang.ClassCastException: sametype cannot be cast to sametype

Tags: java, entitymanager

very strange exception

my code

```
 Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT  u FROM Chatuser u");

            List<Chatuser> list = (List<Chatuser>) q.getResultList();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Object aa = list.get(i);
                Chatuser chatuser = (Chatuser)aa;
```

exception

```
   ex = (java.lang.ClassCastException) java.lang.ClassCastException: Entities.service.Chatuser cannot be cast to Entities.service.Chatuser
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: try this  Object aa = (Object)list.get(i);

Comment: If you did a redeploy try restarting the server.

I ran into the same problem in jBoss once when I was redeploying an app.

Comment: you sure the createQuery works as it should?

Answer (score 1):

This post probably answers also your question
[Java, getting class cast exception where both classes are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371967/java-getting-class-cast-exception-where-both-classes-are-exactly-the-same)

There could be problem with conflicting Classloaders

Comment: I restarted the pc and it worked "older versions of the class retained in memory causing ClassCastException"

Answer (score 0):

it is because the generics

```
List<Chatuser> list =
```

use this form

```
for(ChatUser u : list) {
u.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

please try the following :

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT  u FROM Chatuser u", Chatuser.class);

List<Chatuser> list = q.getResultList();

for (Chatuser chatuser : list) {
    ....
    chatuser.doSomething();
    ...
}
```

If you set the target Class on the createQuery Method already, you can avoid the downcast.
If its not working, please past more infos, (Chatuser.java) JPA(Hibernate) Version, etc)

Cheers Jens