# Method not found in java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to extract the method from my object with this code:

```
Method[] methods = instance.getClass().getMethods();

for (Method m : methods) {
    System.out.println(">>> " + m.getName());
    for (Class c : m.getParameterTypes()) {
        System.out.println("\t->>> " + c.getName());
    }
}

Object method = instance.getClass().getMethod("initialize", ComponentContext.class);
```

It prints the following otput:

```
>>> initialize
->>> org.hive.lib.component.ComponentContext
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hive.sample.Calculator.initialize(org.hive.lib.component.ComponentContext)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1624)
at org.hive.container.lib.Component.hasRightParent(Component.java:140)
at org.hive.container.lib.Component.<init>(Component.java:118)
at org.hive.container.lib.ComponentController$AppLoader.execute(ComponentController.java:107)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Original source code:

```
class Calculator {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ComponentContext context) {
        //  Do nothing
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

**ADD:** I've changed getting method to:

```
Object method = instance.getClass().getMethod("initialize", org.hive.lib.component.ComponentContext.class);
```

But exception still appears

**ADD 2:** `instance` object was instantiated from the JAR with JCL, could it be the problem?

Comment: Does your calculator class actually extend anything?

Comment: Yeap, there is my abstract class with the single abstract method `initialize`

Comment: strange! the for loop should display the rest of the methods too, such as `toString`, `wait()`,...

Comment: @user2511414 OP trimmed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ComponentContext` class passed to `getMethod()` may not be identical (in the eyes of the JVM) to the one which is dumped by your code - if it is loaded by a different class loader. Check the associated class loaders for equality just to be sure.

This is similar to [Java, getting class cast exception where both classes are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371967/java-getting-class-cast-exception-where-both-classes-are-exactly-the-same)

Comment: `instance` was instantiated with JCL from JAR, could it be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it could be. Please output `c.getClassLoader()` and `org.hive.lib.component.ComponentContext.class.getClassLoader()` to find out.

Comment: +1 A different `ClassLoader` is likely to be the issue here since the imports are same.

Comment: Yeap, you were right - first of them has `org.xeustechnologies.jcl.JarClassLoader@3113c6f6` classloader and second has `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@36ddc581`. Thanks!