# Why can't I cast my object to itself?

Tags: java, serialization

I've got an Object, that is an exact replica of the custom object I'm trying to cast it to. I'm grabbing the ***Object*** from a ***RedisTemplate*** (As seen here [Java redis repository not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092838/java-redis-repository-not-working-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment63627917_38092838))

I've debugged it to the point where my hashoperation is getting the value from redis...It returns the ***JwtToken*** class which I inputted in the first place. Here is a screenshot of the breakpoint, you can see that the hashoperation has found the ***JwtToken*** instance.

[image: Screenshot of breakpoint]

I'm testing to see if it's an ***instanceof JwtToken***, which returns false, I then try run the exact same hashop.get method and cast it straight to the ***JwtToken*** class. It throws the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.userapi.spring.model.JwtToken cannot be cast to com.userapi.spring.model.JwtToken
    at com.userapi.spring.service.JwtTokenServiceImpl.findByUser(JwtTokenServiceImpl.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.userapi.spring.security.JwtFilter.doFilter(JwtFilter.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

Here is what my JwtToken class looks like:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by james on 29/06/2016.
 */
public class JwtToken implements Serializable {
    private String token;
    private int userId;
    // #TODO add in more fields...


    public JwtToken(String token, int userId) {
        this.token = token;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public JwtToken() {

    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {

        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JwtToken{" +
                "token='" + token + '\'' +
                ", userId=" + userId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's serializable, the serial ids might not match, so it believes they're incompatible.

Comment: see if this helps ya: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371967/java-getting-class-cast-exception-where-both-classes-are-exactly-the-same

Comment: @Carcigenicate If it was a `serialVersionUID` problem it would throw `InvalidClassException`.

Comment: It looks like the classes have been loaded with different class loaders.  You could check this by printing or inspecting `oo.getClass().getClassLoader()` and `JwtToken.class.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: @msandiford - `JwtToken` is loading `RestartClassLoader` while `oo` is using `Launcher$AppClassLoader`. Would I just do `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(RestartClassLoader);`? This just throws a compilation error.

Comment: I don't really know enough about the system setup to know how to get the right classloader used.  I'm assuming `RestartLoader` is something that tomcat uses.  `Launcher$AppClassLoader` is likely the default JVM class loader.  Somehow you need to convince the internals of `hashOps` to load classes using the `RestartLoader` from tomcat.  Another option would be to create a new object using serialization.