# Scala Script: Explain this class cast error to ScalaClassLoader on Windows

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

Consider following scala script:

```
import scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val classloaderForScalaLibrary = classOf[ScalaClassLoader.URLClassLoader].getClassLoader
    println(classloaderForScalaLibrary)
    val classloaderForTestClass = this.getClass.getClassLoader
    println(classloaderForTestClass)
    this.getClass.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[ScalaClassLoader.URLClassLoader]
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@71c8becc
scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@71c8becc
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader
        at Main$.main(Test.scala:8)
        at Main.main(Test.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$run$2(ScalaClassLoader.scala:98)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:32)
...
```

**Why can't I cast `ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader` to `ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader`?**

[image]

**Edit:**

On running:

> scala -J-verbose:class Test.scala | grep ScalaClassLoader

The output is:

```
[Loaded scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader from file:/C:/Development/Software/scala-2.12.2/lib/scala-reflect.jar]
...
...
[Loaded scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader from file:/C:/DEVELO~1/Software/SCALA-~1.2/lib/scala-reflect.jar]
```

So there is definitely some shady class loading going on. Now trying to investigate why this is so

Comment: Weird, my classloader(`this.getClass.getClassLoader`) is `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@68de145` and I can assert as instance of `URLClassLoader` (`this.getClass.getClassLoader.asInstanceOf[URLClassLoader]`). What about `new ScalaClassLoader.URLClassLoader(Seq(), null).asInstanceOf[ScalaClassLoader.URLClassLoader]`??

Comment: How are you starting your program? When I use `scala Test.scala` it works for me, when I run it from `sbt` or `IntelliJ` I get a `ClassCastException` with a different class loader.

Comment: @prayagupd You're probably running from an IDE which uses a different classloader. Try running from commandline

Comment: You are right. I was using IDE and class loader was Sun one. `scalac` gives me proper result and casting is working fine. `scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@e6ea0c6`. I'm using scala `2.12.2`

Comment: `ClassCastExceptions` for the **same** class can happen when the class was loaded twice by different classloaders. In that case the classes are not considered equal by the JVM even though the have the same name.

Comment: @Harald As you can see in the screenshot. I don't have any customised classloaders

Comment: @Harald should `scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader` not be loaded only once. Curios who can load it twice?

Comment: @KshitizSharma I am using `scala 2.12.2` on MacOS.

Comment: @prayagupd This is really weird. I though maybe something wrong with my scala installation, so just downloaded and tried 2.11.11. Same results

Comment: I think Herald's theory is right. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371991/432903

Comment: @prayagupd Yes, normally it should be loaded only once, especially in such a simple case. But I've seen CCE in containers with dynamic classloaders where the same class could be loaded by unrelated classloaders.

Comment: @prayagupd That sounds reasonable. But the classloader seems to be the same. See my edit to question

Comment: @KshitizSharma: AFAICT the two classloaders have identical names, but _the classloaders in question_ (that are also Java classes) were in their turn _loaded by different classloaders_, likely from different jars. So, despite being "the same class", they cannot be cast to each other, because they potentially come from different source code, just named identically.

Comment: @9000 The two classloaders seem to have same hashcode (see output). Which makes me think its the same instance. Assuming what you say is true, do you think there is a way to debug this further?

Comment: @KshitizSharma should `this.getClass.getClassLoader.getParent` tell who is the root `ClassLoader`? To me on `scalac` gives `null` which means itself is a Parent Loader. But IDE gives me `sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@5034c75a`.

Comment: Also, do `scala Test.scala -J-verbose:class | grep ScalaClassLoader` which gives all the `ScalaClassLoader` being loaded. for me there is one loading only `[Loaded scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader from /usr/local/scala-2.12.2/lib/scala-reflect.jar`

Comment: @prayagupd Thanks for pointing out the `-J-verbose:class` flag. It did reveal the double class loading. Now I need to figure out why

Comment: Sorry to see you're on Windows. Managing paths & classpaths on Windows is always challenging. Why does anyone use Windows? I need a corporate vpn client available only on Windows.

Comment: @som-snytt Windows 10 has much better hardware and app support. Its command line is crap (even powershell), but that is solved by Cygwin.

Comment: @KshitizSharma :) I just updated cygwin and my environment broke. Of course it's not easy. :) Someday I'll try the Windows support for bash, on a day when I am less lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extend your code a bit more as following:

```
import scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader

object test {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val cl1 = this.getClass.getClassLoader
    println(cl1)
    val c1 = cl1.getClass 
    println(cl1.getClass)
    println(cl1.getClass.getClassLoader)

    println("-------")

    var c2 = classOf[ScalaClassLoader.URLClassLoader]
    println(c2)
    println(c2.getClassLoader)
    println("-------")
    println(c1 == c2)

  }
}
```

you'll get following output:

> scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@5cee5251
>   
> class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader
>   
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4554617c
>   
> -------
>   
> class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader
>   
> scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@5cee5251
>   
> -------
>   
> false

Notice matching hashes `@5cee5251`.
It means that first Scala interpreter loads `ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader` using root Java class loader and then uses that class loader to load all the classes in your script and when you ask for `ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader` in your code it is loaded with another (already loaded) instance of `ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader`. In this way your script is isolated from the "runtime environment" that executes it.

You may find some details at [ScalaClassLoader.asContext](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/util/ScalaClassLoader.scala#L30) method, that you can see in your stack trace, that uses [Thread.setContextClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)) to set itself as the main classloader for the thread that executes your script.

**Update** (Why it works on Mac but doesn't work on Windows)

The major difference between `scala` shell script for *nix and `scala.bat` for Windows is that by default on *nix platforms standard Scala libraries are added to Boot Classpath (see `usebootcp` in the script) while on Windows they are added to the "Usual Classpath". This is important because it defines which class loader will load `scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader` that is used by `scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner`: will it be the root class loader (which is represented as `null` if you call `getClassLoader`) or Application Class Loader (i.e. an instance of `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`). This is important because [`CommonRunner.run`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ObjectRunner.scala#L21) creates an instance of `ScalaClassLoader` using just `urls` without `parent`

```
def run(urls: Seq[URL], objectName: String, arguments: Seq[String]) {
  (ScalaClassLoader fromURLs urls).run(objectName, arguments)
}
```

This means that the parent class loader for the "main" `ScalaClassLoader` will be boot class loader rather than `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` and thus when you ask this "main" `ScalaClassLoader` for class `scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader` it can't find it among classes loaded by its class loaders chain and thus has to load it again. This is the reason why you have two different instances of `ScalaClassLoader` ***class*** in your script.

There are two obvious workarounds (and both are not so good):

- Change `CommonRunner.run` in the Scala source to actually pass current context class loader as the parent to the new `ScalaClassLoader` (might be not that easy ☺)
- Change `scala.bat` to use `-Xbootclasspath/a:` instead of `-cp` for `%_TOOL_CLASSPATH%`. However looking into the  `usebootcp` in the *nix script I can see following comment:

```
# default to the boot classpath for speed, except on cygwin/mingw/msys because
# JLine on Windows requires a custom DLL to be loaded.
unset usebootcp
if [[ -z "$cygwin$mingw$msys" ]]; then
  usebootcp="true"
fi
```

So I suspect that if you want to use `scala.bat` for REPL, moving all Scala libs to the Boot Classpath might be a bad idea. If this is the case, you probably need to create a copy of `scala.bat` (such as `scala_run_script.bat`) change it and use it to run your Scala scripts leaving standard `scala.bat` for REPL.

Comment: Interestingly on Mac OS with Scala 2.12.2 I get the follwing output `scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@5fdef03a`
`class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader`
`null`
`-------`
`class scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader`
`null`
`-------`
`true`  

i.e. no `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` involved and the final comparison returns `true`

Comment: Just like Herald, `c1 == c2` is `true` for me as well on scala 2.12.2 on Mac OS (using scalac compiler) but IDE has `false`.

Comment: @Harald, @prayagupd do you compile it with `scalac` and then run or run this script directly using `scala`  as OP seems to do?

Comment: I did both with the above result

Comment: @Harald, I only have Scala 2.11 on the Mac I have access to but surprisingly I got the same ("good") results there. Moreover, original example with `asInstanceOf` seems to work OK on that Mac as well. Could you check it in  your environment?

Comment: @Harald Could this be a bug with handling of windows paths? Has anyone managed to run this on Windows?

Comment: @KshitizSharma, please take a look at my update with more details on reasons

Comment: @SergGr Awesome! Thanks for all the effort. +1