# quartz jdbc serialize/deserialize object

Tags: java, serialization, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I've got this problem where I can't deserialize object using quartz JobDataMap using JDBC. Same code using RAMJobStore works fine.

I simply created a basic class for testing

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

Then in quartz

```
Test test = new Test();
JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
jobDataMap.put("test", test);
```

And in Quartz job

```
JobDataMap data = context.getMergedJobDataMap();    
Test test = (Test) data.get("test");
```

And the exception I get is this

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.venclovas.quartz.buildings.Test
>   cannot be cast to com.venclovas.quartz.buildings.Test     at
>   com.venclovas.quartz.buildings.BuildingsUpgradeJob.execute(BuildingsUpgradeJob.java:39)
>     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)    at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

When I debug the returned object - it looks perfectly fine to me (before casting)

DB definition

```
| QRTZ_TRIGGERS | CREATE TABLE `QRTZ_TRIGGERS` (
  `SCHED_NAME` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `TRIGGER_NAME` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `TRIGGER_GROUP` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `JOB_NAME` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `JOB_GROUP` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NEXT_FIRE_TIME` bigint(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREV_FIRE_TIME` bigint(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRIORITY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRIGGER_STATE` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `TRIGGER_TYPE` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `START_TIME` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
  `END_TIME` bigint(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CALENDAR_NAME` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `MISFIRE_INSTR` smallint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_DATA` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SCHED_NAME`,`TRIGGER_NAME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_J` (`SCHED_NAME`,`JOB_NAME`,`JOB_GROUP`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_JG` (`SCHED_NAME`,`JOB_GROUP`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_C` (`SCHED_NAME`,`CALENDAR_NAME`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_G` (`SCHED_NAME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_STATE` (`SCHED_NAME`,`TRIGGER_STATE`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_N_STATE` (`SCHED_NAME`,`TRIGGER_NAME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`,`TRIGGER_STATE`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_N_G_STATE` (`SCHED_NAME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`,`TRIGGER_STATE`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_NEXT_FIRE_TIME` (`SCHED_NAME`,`NEXT_FIRE_TIME`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_ST` (`SCHED_NAME`,`TRIGGER_STATE`,`NEXT_FIRE_TIME`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_MISFIRE` (`SCHED_NAME`,`MISFIRE_INSTR`,`NEXT_FIRE_TIME`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_ST_MISFIRE` (`SCHED_NAME`,`MISFIRE_INSTR`,`NEXT_FIRE_TIME`,`TRIGGER_STATE`),
  KEY `IDX_QRTZ_T_NFT_ST_MISFIRE_GRP` (`SCHED_NAME`,`MISFIRE_INSTR`,`NEXT_FIRE_TIME`,`TRIGGER_GROUP`,`TRIGGER_STATE`),
  CONSTRAINT `QRTZ_TRIGGERS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SCHED_NAME`, `JOB_NAME`, `JOB_GROUP`) REFERENCES `QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS` (`SCHED_NAME`, `JOB_NAME`, `JOB_GROUP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Serialized object is stored as blob in `JOB_DATA`

Quartz documentation states that

> The JobDataMap can be used to hold any amount of (serializable) data
>   objects

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.html

So my thinking goes that perhaps this is a problem with DB etc and not with quartz since RAMJobStore works fine? Any ideas?

I know that there are other ways to pass Objects to quartz job and they work e.g.

```
SCHEDULER.getContext().put("buildingsModel", buildingsModel);
```

But I am not going to run quartz with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` which probably means I could get into trouble with concurrent jobs. Passing data via JobDataMap is probably a way to go (to be tested if I can get it working). Another solution would be to just pass primitive types, but again that would mean more load to mysql which I want to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting class cast exception where both classes are exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371967/getting-class-cast-exception-where-both-classes-are-exactly-the-same)

Comment: Ravi looks like this could be it.Quartz provides org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer but I did not have any luck with it. Perhaps passing in primitives is just a better design

Answer (score 0):

deserialization from hexstring : (with jobdata in the form of 0xACED00057 ... remove "0x")

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(Hex.decodeHex(inputString));
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
JobDataMap jobDataMap = (JobDataMap) ois.readObject();
Iterator keys = jobDataMap.keySet().iterator();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    buf.append(key).append("=");
    Object value = jobDataMap.get(key);
    buf.append(value);
          /* output buf */
 }
```